# How to addition of value with matching partner name using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to find the sum of values for "partner_name".

I converted the actual json data into array form, as shown below:

```
Array
(
    [partner_name] => Liquid Education
    [lead_payIn] => 44.00
)
Array
(
    [partner_name] => Yodel Voice
    [lead_payIn] => 44.00
)
Array
(
    [partner_name] => Yodel Voice
    [lead_payIn] => 44.00
)
Array
(
    [partner_name] => Yodel Voice
    [lead_payIn] => 44.00
)
Array
(
    [partner_name] => Yodel Voice
    [lead_payIn] => 44.00
)
```

For "obj", I have some json data, as follows:

```
<?php
$arr= json_decode($obj,true);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value);
}

?>
```

I don't understand how I could add the "partner name" data. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example create a new array using the key as `partner_name` and sum the `lead_payIn` for that partner_name.

Check if the key already exists in the result array. If not, set the current value in the iteration as the start value, else sum the current value with the one already existing for the key in the result array.

```
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $a) {
    array_key_exists(
        $a["partner_name"], $result
    ) ? $result[$a["partner_name"]] += $a["lead_payIn"] : $result[$a["partner_name"]] = $a["lead_payIn"];
}
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Liquid Education] => 44
    [Yodel Voice] => 176
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/4ajJo)